# Button simply wont work, i dont understand why

Tags: html, css, button

so basically i have this lets get fit button, but when i hover over it or click it, it doesnt change cursor or lead to index.html, idk why its not working

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: -2px;
}

.cta-btn {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #ca5558;
  padding: .9rem 1.8rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

a.cta-btn:hover,
a.cta-btn:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: #c94246;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero" id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="sub-headline">
      <span class="first-letter">W</span>orkouts
    </h2>
    <div class="headline-description">

      <div class="single-animation">
        <h5>Made simpler.</h5>
        <a href="index.html" class="btn cta-btn">Let's Get Fit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your bit of code works, probably you have other style messing around ;)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why it isn't working but when I ran it it works. I did not change any of the code from your answer, apart from placing a `<section>` which was **closed but not created**.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .btn{
            display: inline-block;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            margin-right: -2px;
        }

        .cta-btn{
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            background-color: #ca5558;
            padding: .9rem 1.8rem;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 3rem;
            transition: background-color .5s;
        }

        a.cta-btn:hover,
        a.cta-btn:focus{
                color: black;
                background-color: #c94246 ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
     <div class="container">
         <h2 class="sub-headline">
            <span class="first-letter">W</span>orkouts
         </h2>
         <div class="headline-description">
           
             <div class="single-animation">
                 <h5>Made simpler.</h5>
                   <a href="index.html" class="btn cta-btn">Let's Get Fit</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```